# How to split a string into multiple columns using Apache Spark / python on Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, split

Attempting to split a string column into 4 columns: A, B, C, D on Databricks using python.

```
# Load CSV file
df = spark.read.format("csv").options(header='false').load("file path")

# Rename header
RawDataDF = RawDataDF.withColumnRenamed("_c0","raw")

#Attempt to split "raw" into 4 columns:
splitDF = RawDataDF.withColumn("split_raw_arr", split("raw", " "))
uDataDF= uDataDF.withColumn('Column A', splitDF.getItem(0))
uDataDF= uDataDF.withColumn('Column B', splitDF.getItem(1))
uDataDF= uDataDF.withColumn('Column C', splitDF.getItem(2))
uDataDF= uDataDF.withColumn('Column D', splitDF.getItem(3))
```

Error message:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'getItem'
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: how about `splitDF[0]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of split to create individual columns is correct.

However you cannot directly use `getItem` on a dataframe (`splitDF`) , The error you are getting signifies that.

Also you might have missed out the initialization step of `uDataDF` in the question and you are creating a column value based out of `spiltDF` , which is also not possible without a [join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html).

`withColumn` wont allow this, as it takes [Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/column.html) type as the second argument.

You can directly use `splitDF` to create the columns and further select the ones to keep to create a new dataframe - `uDataDF`

## Typical Example - Split

```
input_list = [
  (1,"7 6 10")
  ,(2,"4 59 9")
  ,(4,"5 00 12")
  ,(5,"0 10 241")
  ,(6,"7 19 62")
  ,(7,"1 42 743")
  ,(8,"6 23 90")
]


sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list,['id','raw_str'])

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('A',F.split(F.col('raw_str'),' ').getItem(0).cast(DoubleType()))\
                 .withColumn('B',F.split(F.col('raw_str'),' ').getItem(1).cast(DoubleType()))\
                 .withColumn('C',F.split(F.col('raw_str'),' ').getItem(2).cast(DoubleType()))


uDataDF = sparkDF.select(['A','B','C'])

uDataDF.show()
+---+----+-----+
|  A|   B|    C|
+---+----+-----+
|7.0| 6.0| 10.0|
|4.0|59.0|  9.0|
|5.0| 0.0| 12.0|
|0.0|10.0|241.0|
|7.0|19.0| 62.0|
|1.0|42.0|743.0|
|6.0|23.0| 90.0|
+---+----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you this is very useful, but still having a hard time splitting the string as desired.

Do you have any advice on how I can separate a string into 4 columns by using spaces? In the above example, you separated the string by  '\.'

Ps. splitting by '\ ' or ' ' did not work. Assuming there must be some other convention for spaces?

Comment: Updated the answer , space works just as fine as the delimiter

Comment: Spoke too soon! It worked by using '\t'. Thanks again for all your help

Comment: Accepted! Thanks again Vaebhav :)